# Choppy, stuttery & sped-up sound after update

Tags: sound

My audio has always worked perfectly on this hardware and 12.04. Yesterday I received an update, including a kernel update. Today the sound is periodically stuffed. In youtube, mkv files via VLC and embedded audio in web pages (memrise.com) the sound can become stuttery, sped up or stopped mid play-back.

Where can I go to find if this is a known problem, or report it if it is not? Also, can I find a log that will tell me what packages were updated on my machine yesterday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to check if it is a known problem or report it if it is not?

Execute `ubuntu-bug` and follow the prompts.

> Stuttery sound?

See [bug #1019693](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1019693). Also see [Turning off PulseAudio timer scheduling](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/PositionReporting), which might help.

> Sped-up youtube?

This was seemingly a problem with Google Chrome. A chrome update was pushed the next day (30 June 2012 AEST) which fixed this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, [the solution](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wrhl8iaDzFI) for me was disabling automute.

alsamixer => disable automute

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THIS! This fixed my problem with stuttery audio after doing some updates on Ubuntu 12.10. MASSIVE THANK YOU. Wish I could up vote this twice!

Answer (score 0):

For me the stuttering happened when changing the volume of the song that's playing or when for example playing a song and another sound plays in between then the sound will stutter a bit.

In that case, just mute your microphone if you have one connected (or built-in in your laptop like in my case), then the stuttering stops.